# SED saving 60k+ backup files

Tags: sed

I have A LOT of sed commands to do, and parse A LOT of files, so it generates me A LOT of backup files (60k+) I want to sed edit files in place, but don't make backup. Or saving a backup to a single file overwriting it every time a new command is executed. Trying to add anything after the `-i` would generate me a backup file with another extension.

Deleting all the `*.` files (sed makes backups without extensions) can take A REALLY LONG time.

Thank you

Comment: At least with GNU sed it's enough to specify the `-i` switch without any argument.

Comment: In windows Sed, i specify the -i without any argument, and it generates me random name files, like `sedUblgfS` without extension.

Comment: I see, you don't want sed to create any temporary file at all right? This is impossible because if the file is changed it will be rewritten. It might help to keep the temporary file on a ramdisk, e.g.: `sed -i '/path/to/ramdisk/*' ...`.

Comment: I don't want sed to create anyu backups at all lots of backup files is not interesting. Please, tell me more about keepping the temporary file on a ramdisk. Keeping 60k+ files wont be a trouble? Possible to do on Windows?

Comment: See [the sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html), temporary files cannot be avoided with `-i`. I don't know how to create a ramdisk in windows.

Comment: I have read the sed manual. And it says *"If no extension is supplied, the original file is overwritten without making a backup."* Probably a bug in the Windows version.

Comment: `ssed` from here http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/ssed/ seems to try to do what i need, but it got me a `ssed: cannot rename ./sedDOSSUX: File exists` Tried giving it admin permisions but it wont work.

Comment: Overwritten with the temporary file that `sed` created.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
sed -i ''  ....
```

Comment: on Windows, `sed -i ''` wont work, so i tried, `sed -i ""` it returns me `sed: can't read s/a/b/g no such file or directory` so i tried `sed -i"" ...` it still generates me backups like `sedVVf5d1`

Answer (score 1):

Will

```
sed -i /dev/null ...
```

work for you?

Comment: Probably will on my Fedora. I will try this at home, I'm on windows ATM.